# Find non-overlapping values from two tables in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables as follows:

```
library(data.table)
Input<-data.table("Date"=seq(1:10),"Cycle"=c(90,100,130,180,200,230,250,260,300,NA))
Date Cycle
 1:    1    90
 2:    2   100
 3:    3   130
 4:    4   180
 5:    5   200
 6:    6   230
 7:    7   250
 8:    8   260
 9:    9   300
10:   10   320
 FDate<-data.table("Date"=seq(1:9),"Cycle"=c(90,100,130,180,200,230,250,260,300),"Task"=c("D","A","B,C",NA,"A,D","D","C","D","A,C,D"))
   Date Cycle  Task
1:    1    90     D
2:    2   100     A
3:    3   130   B,C
4:    4   180  <NA>
5:    5   200   A,D
6:    6   230     D
7:    7   250     C
8:    8   260     D
9:    9   300 A,C,D
```

I just want to have an output table with non-overlapped `Date` and corrresponding `Cycle`.
I tried with `setdiff` but it doesn't work. I expect my output like this

```
Date  Cycle
 10     320
```

When I tried this `setdiff(FDate$Date,Input$Date)`
it turns like this `integer(0)`

Comment: I don't know data.table well enough to say for sure, but seems related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47663609/5325862) which gives several options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `fsetdiff` from `data.table` by including only the common columns in both datasets

```
fsetdiff(Input, FDate[ , names(Input), with = FALSE])
#   Date Cycle
#1:   10   320
```

Or a join as @Frank mentioned

```
Input[!FDate, on=.(Date)]
#   Date Cycle
#1:   10   320
```

---

In the OP's code,

```
setdiff(FDate$Date,Input$Date)
```

the first argument is from the 'Date' column from 'FDate' All of the elements in that column is also in the master data 'Input$Date'.  So, it returns `integer(0)`).  If we do the reverse, it would return 10

Comment: With anti-join: `Input[!FDate, on=.(Date)]` assuming "nonoverlapped Date" is sufficient or `Input[!FDate, on=.(Date, Cycle)]`